# UIImage imageWithData: does not release under ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, uiimageview, automatic-ref-counting, nsdata

Hi there i am working on an application which loads images from web for filling up the content view. i am using "MGBox2" for loading up the views into the sections and i am using a modified version of "Photobox" class in the mgbox2 example.

My problem is, when i load images from  the web, the imageview objects retain in the memory even i dismiss/removefromsuperview the viewcontroller and views that contains them.

When i look at to the memory allocations i see that i have tons of "malloc 9.00kb" objects with retain count 1 which points to

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:weakData];
```

line. Heres my whole code for loading image and put it into photobox:

My code looks like a mess, becauase i am constantly trying new things, and i know i have some problems with understanding how arc works.. tried to set the data to __weak but as you can see, still no luck..

also note that if an image url contains "publisher" word in it, i am saving it to the documents directory for caching on disk.

```
- (void)loadPhotoFromURL:(NSString*)photoUrl; {

    bool hasLoaded = NO;
    for(id view in self.subviews){
        if([[view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            hasLoaded = YES;
    }
    if(!hasLoaded){
        id fullPath = photoUrl;
        bool willCachePhoto = NO;
        if([photoUrl rangeOfString:@"publishers"].location!=NSNotFound){
            willCachePhoto = YES;
        }
        NSData* data;
        ASIHTTPRequest* request;
        if(willCachePhoto)
            data = [NewsUtil loadData:[fullPath md5]];
        if(!data){
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullPath];
            request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
            [request startSynchronous];
            data = [request responseData];
            if(willCachePhoto){
                [NewsUtil saveData:data withName:[fullPath md5]];
            }
        }[request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
        // do UI stuff back in UI land
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            @autoreleasepool {
                // ditch the spinner
                UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = self.subviews.lastObject;
                [spinner stopAnimating];
                [spinner removeFromSuperview];

                // failed to get the photo?
                if (!data) {
                    self.alpha = 0.3;
                    return;
                }
                __unsafe_unretained NSData* weakData = data;
                UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:weakData];
                UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
                imageView.image = image;
                [self insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
                imageView.size = self.size;
                imageView.alpha = 0;
                imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
                | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

                // fade the image in
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                    imageView.alpha = 1;
                }];
                for(id v in self.subviews){
                    if([[v class]isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
                        UILabel* lbl = (UILabel*)v;
                        NSLog(@"lbl title: %@",lbl.text);
                        [self bringSubviewToFront:lbl];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }//autorelease pool
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like i have fixed my problem with changine imageWithData to imageWithContentsOfFile constructor. heres my new photobox call:

first i put images into temproraycache (also in few cases into permanent cache), and then i call images from the cache storage with filename...

```
        [wRequest setCompletionBlock:^{
            @autoreleasepool {
//                UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToCachedResponseDataForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoUrl]]];;
                UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToCachedResponseDataForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoUrl]]];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = self.subviews.lastObject;
                    [spinner stopAnimating];
                    [spinner removeFromSuperview];
                    if (!image) {
                        self.alpha = 0.3;
                        return;
                    }
                    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                    imageView.size = self.size;
                    imageView.alpha = 0;
                    imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
                    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
                    __weak UIImageView* wimageView = imageView;
                    [self insertSubview:wimageView atIndex:0];
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
                        wimageView.alpha = 1;
                    }];
                    imageView = nil;
                });
                image = nil;
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are retaining UIImageView instance twice. First when you create it using alloc and then when it is inserted to another view (insertSubview). That parent view will retain it.

Insert: 
    [imageView release];

after the line: [self insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];

EDITED: If you are using ARC then my answer is not valid. Please ignore it.

Comment: i am using ARC, so i canot release it with this command.. but i got the point i am working on it..